# В цикл for увеличивать количество $i

Tags: javascript

Вот такой код.

```
<?For ($i=1; $i<3; $i++){?>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" name="[<?php echo $i; ?>][code]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="[<?php echo $i; ?>][groups]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Группа товара"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="[<?php echo $i; ?>][unit]" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th>
    </tr>
<? }?>
```

Понимаю, что через кнопку примерно такую

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="add_tr();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Новая строка
</button>
```

можно увеличивать количество строк. Подскажите как оформить скрипт, чтобы кнопка выполняла свою функцию

Answer (score 0):

Создаете элементы с помощью document.createElement, вам нужен th и  input, вкладываете их друг в друга с помощью appendChild, также добавляете все к родительскому tr

Comment: Пожалуйста можно подробнее, или ссылку где это описывается

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но мне нужен другой способ, у меня количество строк регулируется циклом FOR, а точнее вот этим условие - $i<3. Подскажите как через JS, не перезагружая страницу увеличивать число 3? Можно вместо 3 ввести переменную, задать ее величину а потом менять. Но как это делать через JS&

Comment: Если я задам вот такое условие For ($i=1; $i<$a; $i++){?>, то мне нужно через JS менять значение $a и количество строк будет меняться

Comment: Вся документация по этим методам в свободном доступе. Да можно просто изменить величину 3 на ту что вам нужна

Comment: Вот мне и нужно величину менять, но чтоб это мог делать пользователь, через кнопку в браузере

Comment: Ну оберните все в функцию, передайте i парметром и пользователь сможет через кнопку звать функцию с нужным параметром

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял