# Влияние на переменную PHP через кнопку JS

Tags: javascript, php

Есть переменная.

```
$a=5
```

Подскажите, как через AJAX можно влиять на нее. К примеру нажатием на кнопку увеличивать или уменьшеть ее значение.

Comment: В рантайме чтоли? где у вас значение переменной хранится?

Comment: Да нигде не хранится. Рантайм не понимаю. У меня цикл For выводит  количество строчек равное $a, вот так For ($i=1; $i<$a; $i++). И мне нужно чтобы нажатием кнопки $a увеличивалась и появлялось дополнительная строка.

Comment: Никак нельзя. Опишите задачу подробнее, что нужно. Нажатие кнопки и появление строки - можно просто в javascript реализовать, никакой ajax и php тут не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо. Задача следующая. Вот здесь описана подробнее https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171958/%d0%92-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb-for-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-i

Answer (score 0):

Переменная должна где-то храниться на сервере или передаваться каждый раз в запросе инкрементированная.
Например:

1. Хранить переменную в сессии и при AJAX запросе инкрементировать её
2. При отдаче страницы на фронт устанавливать JS переменную типа: `let A = <? =$a?>`; по клику передавать через параметры запроса в теле или параметре ссылки`?var=++A`;

В теле ответа передавать кусок нового html с новым элементом и подменять его на фронте. Можно конечно обмениваться JSON между сервером и клиентом, а элементы списка рендерить с помощью JS, но это уже совсем другая история :)